# Python: sort elements of first list by elements of second list

Tags: python

```
dict = {“Liz”: 4, “Garry”: 4, “Barry”:6}
list1 = []
for m in sorted(result_dict, key=result_dict.get, reverse=True):
    list1.append(m)
```

After that we have two lists:

```
list1 = ["Barry","Liz", "Garry"]
list2 = [“Garry”, “Liz”, “Barry”]
```

I want that output be like - if elements had same value in dict, in list1 they should be in order of list2 -> for example, if Garry was first in list2, in list1 he too sould be first after "Barry":

```
list1 = ["Barry", "Garry", "Liz"]
```

Comment: In your output example Garry is second

Comment: I'm not sure where those *two* lists are coming from…?!

Comment: Also, please double check your variable names. `oder`, `order`, `dict`, `result_dict`…?!

Comment: Also, `order = sorted(...)` will do; no need to iterate over `sorted` and `append` items to a list.

Comment: Sorry, I edit problem

Answer (score 0):

The `key` function can return a tuple to break ties. So in your case

```
d = {"Liz": 4, "Garry": 4, "Barry": 6}
list2 = ["Garry", "Liz", "Barry"]
list1 = sorted(d, key=lambda x: (d.get(x), -list2.index(x)), reverse=True)
print(list1)
```

will print

```
['Barry', 'Garry', 'Liz']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use as a key the combination of your current key with the positions on the second list, something like this:

```
dict = {'Liz': 4, 'Garry': 4, 'Barry': 6}
list2 = ['Garry', 'Liz', 'Barry']

dict2 = {key: i for i, key in enumerate(list2)}

list1 = sorted(dict, key=lambda x: (dict.get(x), -1*dict2.get(x)), reverse=True)

print(list1)
```

**Output**

```
['Barry', 'Garry', 'Liz']
```

This approach is faster for large list than using [list.index](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). In fact calling index will make the complexity of the algorithm `O(n*2)` therefore hindering the expected complexity of the sorting algorithm which is `O(n*logn)` using a dictionary will keep it the same.